# the more / the less of the two of you

Tags: articles, adjectives

It's OK to say.

> Who is **the taller** of the two of you?

But how should this issue be treated?

> Which one of the two of you has **the less/the more** money?

According to the rule, it's correct. But it sounds awkward. How can it be remediated?

Comment: Remove both "the"s: *Which one of you has **less/more** money?*

Comment: The question is why THE should be removed since it shouldn't with other adjectives.

Comment: The article before ***more** [adjective]* varies from idiomatically *required* through *optional* to *unwanted*. I think it's totally optional in ***Which of you two is [the] taller?**,* but it's unwanted in ***Which of you has** [the] **more free time**?,* and required in ***Which is [the] more sensible option**?*

Comment: @user1425 Your question is, "*How can it be remediated?*" That's the answer. If you want to know why "the" doesn't appear in this sentence, then edit your question to say so.

Comment: "the less/the more money" may sound awkward to you but that's just a result of your limited exposure to it. It needs no remedy.

Comment: Do you mean mine or all the people who find it awkward as well?

Comment: @user1425: Anyone who finds it awkward most likely feels that way because it's not part of their idiolect and they have had limited exposure to it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "why".

"Taller" directly contains the definition of the property which is being compared. We use "the" with such adjectives.

"more"/"less" does not directly define what is being compared. You need to add the word "money" to understand what is being compared in this example, we do not use "the" in this case.

There is more to the rule than "add 'the' before an adjective".

As gotube said, the first sentence is OK to say, but still sounds awkward. "Which one of you (two) is taller." feels more natural.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are wrong. According to the rule "the" should be used when two objects are compared. Who is the tallest of the three of you? (The is needed) Who is the taller of the two of you? (The is also needed) But with LESS and MORE the situation seems to be different since many people object to using the with them.

Comment: @user1425 is right - **the taller of the two** is correct, even if it does sound awkward to you.

Comment: @user1425  When entities are compared, the definite article is licensed but not obligatory: *Who's tallest of the three of you?*  is idiomatic as is *Who's the tallest of the three of you?* The version without the definite article is conversational but not ungrammatical.

Comment: Will someone please link this rule? I've never heard of it, nor have I ever heard someone use "the" with more/less, in this context. I said the first sentence was awkward, not wrong. :)